# Could a research group weed out less good researchers by requiring mental calculation to join it?

Tags: research-process, mathematics, exams

Does the ability to perform mental maths calculations predict ability to do research in mathematics?

Comment: I think it's fine to close this question. I don't have enough knowledge to be able to figure out how to ask it the best way so I think it was better to ask it than not and then have it get closed so that other people can improve it without invalidating an answer. Go ahead and close it if you want. I think it is not however worth deleting because one of the comments at https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/20784/is-it-common-for-people-to-not-like-getting-any-help-making-a-mathematical-compu seems to suggest that this question is suitable here.

Comment: I would expect there are studies around measuring the effect for various applications - did you check for those?

Comment: On the contrary, I voted to "Leave Open" when I review the close request.. Mental calculation is not equivalent to the ability to do research. The answer to the question may be no. But, this is still a good question worth asking and answering. I see no reason to close it.

Comment: Consider the possibility that those people who can't do mental calculations (fast or at all) may have exactly the type of mind to be able to come up with creative ideas - are all artists mathematicians or are all mathematicians artists?

Comment: I suggest to boil down this wall of text to 'does the ability to perform mental calculation the predict ability to do research?'.

Comment: Sometimes I think we should clearly distinguish quantitative/computational talent from mathematical talent. After controlling for experience and general intelligence, the correlation between them doesn't seem to be a whole lot greater than zero.

Comment: @ElizabethHenning I think astronaut made a mistake. Sometimes people can't be sure ahead of time that what they're doing is not a mistake. I wrote in a comment that other people could edit this question. I don't know for sure but it probably would have been better to edit it and vote to close it until it's really carefully researched how to fix it up but unfortunately, I saw no close link on this question.

Answer (score 6):

This is a ridiculous idea. Ability to do mental arithmetic is just that. Ability to do mental arithmetic. It measures nothing else. Research isn't about performing "stupid" calculations quickly. Are you more interested in people who can check twice as fast if there is a mistake in a computation, or are you interested in people who have amazing ideas and the tenacity to follow through on them?

Now for the personal anecdote. I know many top mathematicians who have trouble with mental arithmetic. In fact, it has happened several times that I sat at a restaurant with several mathematicians (during a conference) and splitting an itemized bill turned into a nightmare. And I'm talking about successful researchers.

I also don't see why you would insist on *mental* computations. Different people think differently. For example, if I don't write down what I'm thinking, it doesn't work; I suspect I'm not alone on this planet of 7 billion people. Other people need to speak, etc.

Comment: But "Bistromathics" is a separate field - see Douglas Adams :) Good answer though...

Answer (score 1):

All other things being equal, skills at mental arithmetic are likely to give a small in edge in some fields of mathematics. They could find a mistake faster, or perform parts of an involved calculation faster. I would guess that skills at mental arithmetic also correlate with general numeracy, which correlates with the ability to get university mathematics studies done, so a connection to ability as a researcher is possible.

However, by the time you are hiring someone, or even taking someone as a student, they already have research output or at least grades and completed courses. These include the information about how much their skills at mental arithmetic benefits or hampers them. As such, I suggest disregarding the person's ability at mental arithmetic when hiring them.

Comment: [long monologue removed by moderator] Would a question of this sort be suitable on any Stack Exchange website? If not, could I asked other questions whose answers will give me the resources to ask that question in a way that does belong on one Stack Exchange website?

Comment: For on-topicness of questions, ask at relevant Meta websites. If you want to ask how to test mental arithmetic abilities of someone or whether your suggested scheme would do it, matheducators might be a relevant SE website. Please check the help center for what is on topic there before asking.